# Git History and Rebase issue

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-commit

I do a commit to my local repo, then I pushed it to origin after that I amended the commit and tried to push it but I got an error saying that I need to pull from origin, I made that and a conflict happened I fixed it and committed the change to local and remote repos. Now my commit history is horrible here it is:

[image]
The commit I made named: **An early version of the ImportImageModel**

How I can rebase the history to fix these unnecessarily commits?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but after a `commit --amend`, you have to force push `push -f`, because you rewrote the commits history.

Comment: I also tried that, but it failed, unfortunately I don't remember the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Interactive rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages) should do the trick. It allows do to many things, among them removing commits.

Answer (score 1):

In your HEAD, type

git rebase -i HEAD~20

And interactive editor will be prompted up.

You can manipulate how's your commit would look like e.g. Delete the line commit, squeeze into one commit, see the instruction of the text

Save it

then your target result is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Kit, but I am afraid of rewriting history of the remote repo, it may result in some conflicts, is there no option other than this?